# Xcode Framework Search Path

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an Xcode project set up with multiple frameworks. The file structure is as follows:

```
Project
|
 -workspace
|
 -framework_1
  |
   - framework_1.xcodeproj
|
 -framework_2
  |
   - framework_2.xcodeproj
```

framework_1 depends on framework_2. How do I set up the framework search paths in framework_1 to correctly see framework_2?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do but I drag each project into the workspace and they find each other just fine.